# Can I develop on SQL Server 2005 and deploy to SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

My development under VS2008 Team Suite SP1 with SQL Sever 2005 Express SP3. One of my customer only have SQL Server 2000 License.

I don't start my project yet. So I want to find a way that I can develop on SQL Server 2005 but deploy to SQL Server 2000.

Thanks SO and every folks here so much.

PS：I tried Database Project included in VS 2008. I start a SQL Server 2000 project but I can't import database schema from my SQL Server 2005. So I think it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create the database there is a compatibility level option.  It should be under the options menu on the New Database dialog.  You can set that to SQL Server 2000 (80).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I always manage my database using visual studio build-in management tools, when I works in sql server management studio, I find the option.

Answer (score 1):

Addition to what blu said...

Make sure you don't use any new features (T-SQL wise)..

See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189465(SQL.90).aspx) to find out what to avoid.